# JEST - How to check the prop- actions getting called from the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am new to the React and Jest and I am trying to test my function where : I have a function :

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    this.changeData().then(() => {
        const payload = {
            somePayload: 'sample'
        };
        this.props.actions.authenticate(payload);
    });
};
```

and the jest function as :

```
it('test mock test', () => {
    const actionsMock = { authenticate: jest.fn() };
    const localWrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent actions={actionsMock} />);
    const instance = localWrapper.instance();
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleSubmit');
    instance.forceUpdate();
    localWrapper.find('.button').simulate('click');
    expect(actionsMock.authenticate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({somePayload: 'sample'});
});
```

So, In this case, when I click on the button it calls the `handlesubmit` function and eventually the `this.props.actions.authenticate(payload);` but when I assert the same in Jest it gives me error that function was never called.

**EDIT**

As in the comment CJ Pointed: I see that my assertion is getting called even before the promise for changeData resolved. So, How I can I make my assertion wait till the promise gets resolved?

Comment: Hi @vaibhav! I have not yet attempted to recreate this, but from inspection it appears the issue might be that since changeData() is returning a promise, your assertion might be called before the promise is resolved. Try putting a console.log(1) after the simulated button click, right before the assertion, and a console.log(2) right before the authenticate call to see which executes first. If they are called in the correct order, then we can look at what else could be causing the issue.

Comment: Oh you were absolutely right, @CJNaude. This indeed was the issue. my assertion is getting called before the promise could return the value. Any Solution to that? Also, I am updating my question for the same.

Comment: Hi @vaibhav this seems to be a feasible solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/3977134

Comment: Here's the official jest docs on dealing with promises in tests: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises 
You can also mock the changeData function so that it executes synchronously, but I suppose at that point your test is just checking that handleSubmit is called and authenticate is in there.

Comment: @r3dst0rm. this is exactly I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CJNaude, Thaks a lot for pointing the mistake and then navigating to the right direction for the solution :)