# Testing subsequent function call on an Async function from React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test that `navigate` function is called.  I've mocked the component with a jest, but due to the async / promise function it doesn't call the function in time for the test

**Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
...
import { Dialog } from '../../../../common/components/Dialog';

const Component = () => {

  ...

  const handleSave= async (value) => {
    const { id } = await newRecord(value);
    navigate(APP_ROUTES.SOMELOCATION(id));
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleSave(someValue)} />
  );
};
```

**Test**

```
import { navigate } form '@reach/router';
jest.mock('@reach/router');


it('should call navigate when button is clicked', () => {
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

It does however work if you do:
`setTimeout(() => { expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalled() }, 100)`

Comment: Where is `navigate` defined?

Comment: on line 1: import { navigate } form '@reach/router';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coming across: [Stackoverflow: Flush all promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741102/how-to-make-jest-wait-for-all-asynchronous-code-to-finish-execution-before-expec)

I added this to my test and it appears to be passing now.  So now my test looks like this:

```
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);


it('should call navigate when button is clicked', async () => {
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  await flushPromises();
  expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this happend because mouse click is asynchronous, so you should wait until it ends, try this:

```
it('should call navigate when button is clicked', async () => {
  await wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Hi @I_Shayderov unfortunately that didn't work. Although I think that was part of the solution.