# How to properly mock `antd` Upload Dragger with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

I have the following react code in my project

```
import React from 'react';
import { Upload } from 'antd';

const { Dragger } = Upload;

...

<Dragger
  accept={ACCEPTED_FORMATS}
  beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
  data-testid="upload-dragger"
  maxCount={1}
  onChange={({ file: { status } }) => {
    if (status === 'done') onUploadComplete();
  }}
  progress={progress}
  showUploadList={false}
>
{/* here i have a button, code ommited for clarity, if needed i'll post it */}
</Dragger>
```

And I want to test if the callback function `onUploadComplete()` was called when file.status is `'done'`.

Here is how i am doing the test right now:

1. I have a jest.mock to simulate a *dumb request* that will always succeed

```js
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { DraggerProps } from 'antd/lib/upload';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

import UploadCompanyLogo from '../UploadCompanyLogo'; // This is the component where the dragger is placed

jest.mock('antd', () => {
  const antd = jest.requireActual('antd');
  const { Upload } = antd;
  const { Dragger } = Upload;

  const MockedDragger = (props: DraggerProps) => {
    console.log('log test');
    return (
      <Dragger
        {...props}
        action="greetings"
        customRequest={({ onSuccess }) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            onSuccess('ok');
          }, 0);
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return { ...antd, Upload: { ...Upload, Dragger: MockedDragger } };
});
```

2. The test itself (same file as the mock), where it renders the component (where `antd` will be imported), simulate an upload and then checks if the callback has been called.

```
it('completes the image upload', async () => {
    const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);

    const { getByTestId } = render(elementRenderer({ onUploadComplete }));

    const file = new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'chucknorris.png', { type: 'image/png' });

    const uploadDragger = await waitFor(() => getByTestId('upload-dragger'));

    await act(async () => {
      userEvent.upload(uploadDragger, file);
    });

    await flushPromises();

    expect(onUploadComplete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(onUploadComplete).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });
```

3. elementRenderer

```
const elementRenderer = ({
  onUploadComplete = () => {}
}) => (
  <ApplicationProvider>
    <UploadCompanyLogo
      onUploadComplete={onUploadComplete}
    />
  </ApplicationProvider>
);
```

4. ApplicationProvider

```
import React, { PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import { ConfigProvider as AntdProvider } from 'antd';
import { RendererProvider as FelaProvider } from 'react-fela';
import { createRenderer } from 'fela';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';

import antdExternalContainer, {
  EXTERNAL_CONTAINER_ID,
} from 'src/util/antdExternalContainer';
import { antdLocale } from 'src/util/locales';
import rendererConfig from 'src/fela/felaConfig';
import i18n from 'src/i18n';

const ApplicationProvider = (props: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <AntdProvider locale={antdLocale} getPopupContainer={antdExternalContainer}>
      <FelaProvider renderer={createRenderer(rendererConfig)}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <div className="antd-local">
            <div id={EXTERNAL_CONTAINER_ID} />
            {children}
          </div>
        </I18nextProvider>
      </FelaProvider>
    </AntdProvider>
  );
};

export default ApplicationProvider;
```

This is currently not working, but have already been improved with the help of [@diedu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1868008/diedu).

The `console.log()` I have put in the MockedDragger it's currently not showing. If I put a `console.log()` in both component and mockedDragger, it prints the component log.

Any tips on how to proceed?
I have already seen this [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21080) and didn’t help.

Comment: What will happen when onUploadComplete() is called? I think it would be a success message right? I would recommend you to test that success message.

Comment: onUploadComplete will trigger some database stuff, nothing that is very important to the test. I tried logging some messages and it works fine on the browser (when status is 'error' or 'uploading', since it never really completes the upload. I want to simulate the 'done' status to make sure this callback is always called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should change is the return you are doing in your mock. You are returning a new component called `MockedDragger`, not `Dragger`.

```
  return { ...antd, Upload: { ...Upload, Dragger: MockedDragger } };
```

The next thing is the event firing. According to [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/93) you should use RTL user-event library and wrap the call in `act`

```
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

...
  await act(async () => {
    userEvent.upload(uploadDragger, file);
  });
...
```

and finally, due to some asynchronous code running [you need to flush the pending promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741102/how-to-make-jest-wait-for-all-asynchronous-code-to-finish-execution-before-expec) before checking the call

```
  const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
  ...
  await flushPromises();
  expect(onUploadComplete).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

this is the full version

```
import { render, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { DraggerProps } from "antd/lib/upload";

jest.mock('antd', () => {
  const antd = jest.requireActual('antd');
  const { Upload } = antd;
  const { Dragger } = Upload;

  const MockedDragger = (props: DraggerProps) => {
    return <Dragger {...props} customRequest={({ onSuccess }) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        onSuccess('ok');
      }, 0)
    }} />;
  };

  return { ...antd, Upload: { ...Upload, Dragger: MockedDragger } };
});

it("completes the image upload", async () => {
  const onUploadComplete = jest.fn();
  const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);

  const { getByTestId } = render(
    <App onUploadComplete={onUploadComplete} />
  );

  const file = new File(["(⌐□_□)"], "chucknorris.png", { type: "image/png" });

  const uploadDragger = await waitFor(() => getByTestId("upload-dragger"));
  await act(async () => {
    userEvent.upload(uploadDragger, file);
  });
  await flushPromises();
  expect(onUploadComplete).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Unfortunately, I [couldn't set up](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/513) a codesandbox to show it's working, but let me know if you face any issue and I can push the code to a repo.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! But unfortunately still not working :(. I always get `Received number of calls: 0`. Do you need more info? My dragger is inside of some divs and has others props, such as beforeUpload and so on.

Comment: Also, I don’t know how much this is useful, but if I insert a `console.log` inside the `jest.mock`'s callback, it never logs the message. Could it be something about the mock not working? Like, it's not mocking the Dragger for real. Just a hypothesis..

Comment: @GabrielMichelassi I actually put the `console.log` in the mock and I see it when running the test, please checkout this repo to see what could be different from your actual code https://github.com/diedu89/antd-dragger-test

Comment: Thank you for the repo, it's very useful for me, but I still can't find why the mock does not work for me. Appreciate the effort tho, I'll keep looking and If i got news I'll post here

Comment: @GabrielMichelassi could you update your answer with the code you have now? I can help to identify what could be different

Comment: done! if you need any other change I'll make it

Comment: the only difference I see is that you're using the `elementRenderer` function instead of rendering the component in the test, is that function from another file? maybe that's why is not getting the mock

Comment: Added the `elementRenderer` and also the `ApplicationProvider` that's used on it

Comment: is that function in the same file as the test?

Comment: yes, it is... it's placed after the `imports` and before the `jest.mock()` thing

Comment: ok, I'll try later to set a similar configuration on my code to see if that's the problem

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233770/discussion-between-diedu-and-gabriel-michelassi).