# How to test the document.documentElement with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

Here is the mini react project: https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-monad-n32vv

I try my best to make it as small as I can. To let `tailwindcss` open `dark mode`, we need to add `"dark"` to the `document.documentElement`'s `classList`. So the mini project will add or remove (aka, toggle) the class name `"dark"` to `classList` after we click the button.

It works really well. But the Jest test failed.

Here is the test file in the mini project:

```js
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App.js";

test("<App />", () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  const darkToggle = getByText("Toggle");
  document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
  expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(false);

  fireEvent.click(darkToggle);
  expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(true);
  fireEvent.click(darkToggle);

  // it failed here!!!!
  expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(false);

  fireEvent.click(darkToggle);
  expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(true);
});
```

I read a lot but cannot find something useful. Mocking DOM by JSDOM looks do not work -- Looks like that the new version Jest's default env is JSDOM. I also failed to test localStorage(I remove those in the mini project), I hope those failed because the same bug.

My guess: after use Redux, the test failed. I think the test failed because of `createAsyncThunk`. But I still have no idea.

EDITED: **I find this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/13031497**

EDITED: **I resolve it. But looks like the codesandbox still raise error?**

Answer (score 0):

After try, I find `await new Promise(process.nextTick);` does well.

I think because `createAsyncThunk`'s function will change the data after test -- really bad. If there is some function that can sleep some time after the data has already changed, it will be the BEST!!! I find this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/13031497, it tell my change the test file like:

```
  import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
  import App from "./App.js";
  
  test("<App />", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<App />);
    const darkToggle = getByText("Toggle");
    document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(false);
  
    fireEvent.click(darkToggle);
 +  await new Promise(process.nextTick);
    expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(true);
 +
    fireEvent.click(darkToggle);
- 
-   // it failed here!!!!
 +  await new Promise(process.nextTick);
    expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(false);
  
    fireEvent.click(darkToggle);
 +  await new Promise(process.nextTick);
    expect(document.documentElement.classList.contains("dark")).toBe(true);
  });
```

Then the test pass.