# React Native: 'Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed' with @testing-library/react-hooks and react-query

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, jestjs, react-query, testing-library

I am using `jest` and `@testing-library/react-hooks` to test hooks implemented with `react-query` in my React Native code.

The tests work ok, but at the end, I am getting:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

Here is my simplified code:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import React from 'react'
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query'

const useSomething = () => {
  return useQuery('myquery', () => 'OK')
}

beforeAll((done) => {
  done()
})

afterAll((done) => {
  done()
})

// test cases
describe('Testing something', () => {
  it('should do something', async () => {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient()
    const wrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactFragment }) => (
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>{children}</QueryClientProvider>
    )
    const { result, waitFor } = renderHook(() => useSomething(), { wrapper })

    await waitFor(() => {
      return result.current.isSuccess
    })

    expect(result.current.data).toBe('OK')

  })
```

})

I tried using `cleanup`, `done`, `unmount`, etc. before each/all with no results. If I remove `useQuery` from `useSomething`, the problem disappears.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been reported in the past here:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/1847

The issue is caused by the react-query garbage collection timer running, which defaults to 5 minutes. Solutions are, as described in the issue:

- clearing the queryCache after each test:
  `afterEach(() => { queryClient.clear() });`
- setting `cacheTime` to `0` for your test, e.g. with: `queryClient.setDefaultOptions({ queries: { cacheTime: 0 } })`
- using `jest.useFakeTimers()`

Answer (score 2):

You could try defining a function like:

```
export function flushPromises() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));
}
```

Then on your test before the `expect`:

```
await flushPromises();
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51045733/5976591)