# How to flush promises since Jest 26+

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Jest 26 shipped a new implementation of fake timers based on @sinonjs/fake-timers.

Previously I used
`const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);`

and now I'm trying to replace it with

`await new Promise(process.nextTick);`

as described here:
[How to make Jest wait for all asynchronous code to finish execution before expecting an assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44741102/how-to-make-jest-wait-for-all-asynchronous-code-to-finish-execution-before-expec)
but it doesn't work in some cases.

Example code when it doesn't work (jest version: 27.5.1):

```
class SuperFetch {
    public static async get(): Promise<string> {
        return 'never mind';
    }
}

class ClassForTest {
    public async get(): Promise<string> {
        return SuperFetch.get();
    }
}
```

Test1 with legacy fake timers (passed):

```
jest.useFakeTimers('legacy');
describe('Test', () => {

    const flushPromises = (): Promise<void> => new Promise(setImmediate);
    
    test('should flush promise', async () => {
        SuperFetch.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test');
        const instance = new ClassForTest();
        let result;
        instance.get().then(x => {
            result = x;
        });

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
        await flushPromises();

        expect(result).toBe('test');
    });
});
```

Test2 with modern fake timer (failed)

```
jest.useFakeTimers('modern');
describe('Test', () => {
    test('should flush promise', async () => {
        SuperFetch.get = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('test');
        const instance = new ClassForTest();
        let result;
        instance.get().then(x => {
            result = x;
        });

        jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000);
        await new Promise(process.nextTick);

        expect(result).toBe('test');
    });
});
```

Failed with
**thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.**
During debugging it freezes on `await new Promise(process.nextTick)`

Answer (score 4):

For my test I am using the `flushPromises` method as you described:

```js
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);
```

but to make this work I had to import `setImmediate`:

```js
import { setImmediate } from 'timers';
```